# Deserialize JSON with variable key

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Having this json format data:

```
{
    "43296001103418946331805279000": {
      "city": "43296001",
      "district": "43296001-1034189463",
      "floor": "5",
      "price": "279000",
      "rooms": "3",
      "size": "80"
    },
      "432960018694019521321777312000": {
      "city": "43296001",
      "district": "43296001-86940195213",
      "floor": "7",
      "price": "312000",
      "rooms": "2",
      "size": "77"
    }
}
```

I have this class:

```
public class Flat
{
  public string city{ get; set; }
  public string district{ get; set; }
  public string floor{ get; set; }
  public string price{ get; set; }
  public string rooms{ get; set; }
  public string size{ get; set; }
}
```

But how can I deserialize the object if the key is a variable id?

Comment: Deserialize to a dictionary. In this case `Dictionary<string, Flat>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use this way:

```
var out = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ISBN>>(json);        
var isbn_out = out.Values.First();
```

then use it with:

```
 isbn_out.Flat.city;
```

take a look at this [similar example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/csgSKp).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would have:

```
public class JsonData
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, Flat>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and then you deserialize this doing:

```
JsonData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(json);
```